# extract array value on click jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, object, extract

Trying to achieve the following with `extractAssets();`

- When clicking on `.clickable` extract asset `(lists[i].assets)` value by itself to 0 (something like `lists[i].assets - lists[i].assets`).

As you may see I'm not extracting but doing a .html("$0"), so a dynamic extraction would be desired.

[see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaxjLvgs/5/)

Working fiddle example is appreciated, thank you.

```js
var list1 = {
  id: 7,
  assets: 74651.90,
  ratePercent: 0.02,
  rateUSD: 24.03
};
var list2 = {
  id: 8,
  assets: 86735.79,
  ratePercent: -0.06,
  rateUSD: 2.41
};

var lists = [list1, list2];

$(document).ready(function() {
  show();
  extractAssets();
});

function extractAssets() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    //var text = $(".coin" + [i]).text();
    $(".clickable" + [i]).click(function() {
      //$(".coin" + [i]).text(text == $(this).text() - $(this).text() ? $(this).text() - $(this).text() : $(this).text());
      $(this).find(".coin").html("$0");
      //$(".coin" + [i]).text(text == $(this).text() ? "$0" : $(this).text());
    })
  }
}

function show() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    $(".DataContent").append('<div class="clickable' + [i] + '"><p class="data">' + lists[i].id + '</p><ul><li class="coin">$' + lists[i].assets + '</li><li class="rate"><span class="ratePercent">' + lists[i].ratePercent.toFixed(2) + '%</span> / <span class="rateUSD">$' + lists[i].rateUSD.toFixed(2) + '</span></li></ul></div>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="DataContent"></section>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve ..its little unclear now

Comment: I apologize in that case, it's basically the exact same behavior as in the fiddle, but instead of setting it via .html("$0") on click, it would be preferred to extract the clicked asset by itself (e.g. clicking on $86735.79 extract it by the same amount ($86735.79) which would result in 0)

Comment: Please post your code here, not just at jsfiddle. Use [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Comment: @Barmar, I added the code, hope that helps? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bit weird to me that you're using the data for reference, but using the html dom elements for operations. I hardly recommend to us a templating language. Anyways... with your actual code this is what I would update:

```
function extractAssets() {
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
        var currentCoin = $(this).find('.coin');
      var difference = (Number($(currentCoin).text().replace('$','')) - Number($(currentCoin).text().replace('$','')));
      $(currentCoin).html('$' + difference);
        });
}

function show() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    $(".DataContent").append('<div class="clickable"><p class="data">' + lists[i].id + '</p><ul><li class="coin">$' + lists[i].assets + '</li><li class="rate"><span class="ratePercent">' + lists[i].ratePercent.toFixed(2) + '%</span> / <span class="rateUSD">$' + lists[i].rateUSD.toFixed(2) + '</span></li></ul></div>');
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this does not format the amount at the end.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Espino but it's not what I'm looking for. Also, yes I agree and hence I'm asking advice, I prefer a real extraction and not setting a 0 via .html(). Have a great day.

Comment: mmm Have you tried the code?

`var difference = (Number($(currentCoin).text().replace('$','')) - Number($(currentCoin).text().replace('$','')));` that line does the extraction, not setting to 0. What do you think is missing?

Comment: my bad, re-tried pasting everything and seems right, give me a few minutes to fully adapt it and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you for the help and for insisting :)

Comment: :D! no prob, glad to help

Comment: Sorry David, any chance you can adjust what you did but with this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaxjLvgs/6/) ?, it's identical but added `.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")` to `lists[i].assets` to give currency format, so now your solution returns $NaN. I've tried many tweaks but nothing, million thanks!

Comment: Done... I've updated it. In case it is not saved, just change the replace to this `.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")`. Regards